# Can NSURLSessionDownloadTask resume called twice?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession

I am new to NSURLSession and i did not find the answer in other stackoverflow question. So i am posting this.

I am having a Button and ProgressBar in my ViewController. Using `NSURLSessionDownloadTask`'s instance, i am calling `resume` as follows

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask;
```

Specified above line in `@interface`

```
 NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
 NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfiguration delegate:self delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];
 self.downloadTask = [session downloadTaskWithURL:url];
```

Specified above lines in `@implementation` and called `resume` method on buttonclick as follows

```
-(void) buttonpressed:(id)sender{
    [self.downloadTask resume];
}
```

---

Here what happens is,

When i click the button for first time, it downloads perfectly

(ie. Calling the proper delegate methods 
`downloadTask:didWriteData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite` &  `didFinishDownloadingToURL`

But when i click the button again, it's not downloading (ie. Delegate methods are not calling)

> 1) Where i am doing mistake?
>
> 2) I want it to download again if i click the button second time. What
>   should i do for that?

Any help appreciated, thanks for the time (:

Comment: where are you calling downloadTaskWithURL ?

Answer (score 1):

`resume` is only for suspended tasks, and yours is completed.  The simple fix is to create and begin (really, resume) the task in the same function.

```
- (void)setupAndStartDownload {
    // your setup code, from the OP
    // then start it here
    [self.downloadTask resume];
}

-(void) buttonpressed:(id)sender{
    [self setupAndStartDownload];
}
```

Comment: I don't know how it will be created if we call that in separate function.  I mean, both are same right?

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment.  I'm suggesting that you create and resume the session in the same function.  Call that function the first time, and then again via the button code.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand.  What I want is,whenever I click the button, it should re-download which will not happen even if I specify a function inside button action

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand if you've tried the idea and it's not working, or if you don't think it will work for some reason.  Think of creating and starting the task as just one operation.  (In fact, don't even keep a downloadTask property.  Just create a new one in a local variable, start it and forget it).  Do that whenever you want to download.

Comment: Yes.  I think it's perfectly good practice.  The thing to watch out for is to make sure that your "download again" button isn't available to the user until *after* the download is finished.  You probably don't want the user restarting the same download while it's already in progress.